# Is saying "I propose that..." expressing a proposition or not?

Tags: propositions

i'm trying to find out how to accurately express propositions, but i can't find the right words. If i say something like... "I propose that the detective was bias.", does this make sense as expressing a proposition i.e. the "I propose that ____" is a template for expressing propositions? If not is there anything such like this which i could use?

Thanks

Comment: Just say, "The detective was biased." That is a proposition. "I propose that the detective was biased" is unneeded extra verbiage, although it has essentially the same meaning.

Comment: "The detective was biased" is a proposition, "I propose that the detective was biased" is a proposition with a [propositional attitude](https://iep.utm.edu/prop-ati/) attached. The latter is a relation between the subject and the proposition, so the phrase expresses more than the proposition itself. Other attitudes, "I believe", "I know", "I wish", work the same way.

Comment: What's difference between propose and know? Simple etymology here may be hintful...